# Python - how to read path file/folder from server

Tags: python

Using Python, how might one read a file's path from a remote server?
This is a bit more clear to me on my local PC.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 8):

See [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/tut/node9.html#SECTION009200000000000000000) in the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/tut/tut.html), which is a great place to start for a newbie.

Be sure to escape your backslashes on Windows, *viz*:

```
f=open('\\\\SERVER\\share\\file.ext', 'r')
```

or use ["raw" strings](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/tut/node5.html#SECTION005120000000000000000):

```
f=open(r'\\SERVER\share\file.ext', 'r')
```

Comment: Raw strings are nicer for Windows paths - `f=open(r'\\SERVER\share\file.ext', 'r')`

Answer (score 0):

use the `os.path` module to manipulate path string (you need to `import os`)

- the current directory is `os.path.abspath(os.curdir)`
- join 2 parts of a path with `os.path.join(dirname, filename)`: this will take care of inserting the right path separator ('\' or '/', depending on the operating system) for building the path