# Python - how one can read path file/folder from server

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Question related to an earlier asked question ([Python - how to read path file/folder from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163456/python-how-to-read-path-file-folder-from-server)). I have similar issue- I am using python and used `f=open('\\SERVER\share\file.ext', 'r')` to open/access folder in a remote server- but its still giving me an error "no such file directory" can you please help me with that.

What I am trying to do is to goto my remote server and read that particular file and upload on my sql database. I am using pyodbc and connection to db is fine, I can query select and even insert individual values in table. But I want to do either a load data local infile query or insert as a loop around my csv file.
this is what i have

```
dsn=name; pw=password
def func(dsn):
    connection = pyodbc.connect(dsn)
    connection.autocommit =True
    cur = connection.cursor()
    csv_data = open (r'\\server-ipaddress\C:\foldername\filename.csv','r')
    for row in csv_data:
            cur.execute("insert into table_name values(?)",row)
```

Comment: The top answer in the question you linked points out at least one issue you have with your `open` command. Try to apply the suggestion given there first, then come back if you are still experiencing issues. Also, please include the full stacktrace of the error you are getting.

Comment: Yes I tried using f=open('\\\\SERVER\\share\\file.ext', 'r') or two back slashes using raw string. It still doesnt work. I suppose share is the folder name in the example above

Comment: Then please include the full error you are getting.

Comment: this is what I have:

dsn=name; pw=password
def func(dsn):
      connection = pyodbc.connect(dsn)
      connection.autocommit =True
      cur = connection.cursor()
      csv_data = open (r'\\server-ipaddress\C:\foldername\filename.csv','r')
       for row in csv_data:
                             cur.execute("insert into table_name values(?)",row)

Comment: Please update your question with the new information. That's easier to read there with proper formatting.

Comment: I have edited- thanks

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `C:` would be an invalid path segment. Please try to find and open the path in your Explorer first, and insert the correct one into your script.

Comment: I checked the location/path of the file from properties and it is C:\folder_name-

Comment: C: is the drive on the server, but the share will have a name that doesn't include C:

Comment: I am sorry barny- but im not sure what you meant. how does this \\server\share work
'\\server-ipaddress\C:\foldername\filename.csv' - 
should I write it like this?
'\\server-ipaddress\share\foldername\filename.csv'

Comment: Can someone please help with my question. I would really appreciate explanation. I need it to done fast and nothing on my end is working.