# How to read an excel file directly from a Server with Python

Tags: python, pandas, os.path

**Scenario:** I am trying to read a excel file from a server folder and after that read each worksheet of that file into a dataframe and perform some operations.

**Issue:** I have trying multiple approaches but facing different situations: either I read the file, but it is seen as a str and the operations cannot be performed, or the file is not read.

**What I tried so far:**

```
#first attempt
os.path(r'\\X\str\Db\C\Source\selection\Date\Test','r')  

#second attempt
directory = os.getcwd() + "\\C\\Source\\selection\\Date\\Test"

#third attempt
f = os.getcwd() + "\\C\\Source\\selection\\Date\\Test\\12.xlsx"

#fourth attempt
f = open(r'\\X\str\Db\C\Source\selection\Date\Test\12.xlsx', 'r')

db1 = pd.DataFrame()
db2 = pd.DataFrame()
db3 = pd.DataFrame()
bte = pd.DataFrame()
fnl = pd.DataFrame()

wb = load_workbook(f)

for sheet in wb.worksheets:

    if sheet.title == "db1":

        db1 = pd.read_excel(f, "db1")
```

**Obs:** I also researched the documentation for reading with pd and some other similar questions in SO, but still could not solve this problem. Ex:
[Python - how to read path file/folder from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163456/python-how-to-read-path-file-folder-from-server)
[Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)
https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/tut/node9.html#SECTION009200000000000000000

**Question:** What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file as rb mode

b = bynary file
r = only read the file

```
f = open('//X/str/Db/C/Source/selection/Date/Test/12.xlsx', 'rb')
```

You can use [pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) that will do most of the work for you

import pandas

```
import pandas
f = pandas.read_excel(open('//X/str/Db/C/Source/selection/Date/Test/12.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='Sheet 1')
# or using sheet index starting 0
f = pandas.read_excel(open('//X/str/Db/C/Source/selection/Date/Test/12.xlsx','rb'), sheetname=2)
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590692/4175515)

Comment: The Second part works perfectly. I do not have to reload the workbook into a variable. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Try Pandas and forward slashes

```
pd.read_excel('//X/str/Db/C/Source/selection/Date/Test/12.xlsx')
```

Have to work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

[From here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)

Try using forward slashes in your UNC path:

```
f = open('//X/str/Db/C/Source/selection/Date/Test/12.xlsx', 'rb')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried that, it yields a new error: OSError: File-object must be opened in binary mode.

Comment: use f =open('//X/str/Db/C/Source/selection/Date/Test/12.xlsx', 'rb'). xls is not a text file, is a bynary file. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open