# Merge Pandas Dataframe on a column with structured data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** Following up from a previous question on how to read an excel file from a serve into a dataframe ([How to read an excel file directly from a Server with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740273/how-to-read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-server-with-python)), I am trying to merge the contexts of multiple dataframes (which contain data from excel worksheets).

**Issue:** Even after searching for similar issues here in SO, I still was not able to solve the problem.

**Format of data (each sheet is read into a dataframe):**

```
Sheet 1 (db1)
Name       CUSIP       Date       Price

 A          XXX     01/01/2001     100
 B          AAA     02/05/2005      90
 C          ZZZ     03/07/2006      95

Sheet2 (db2)
Ident      CUSIP       Value      Class

 123        XXX          0.5        AA
 444        AAA          1.3        AB
 555        ZZZ          2,8        AC
```

Wanted output (fnl):

```
Name       CUSIP       Date       Price       Ident       Value      Class
 A          XXX     01/01/2001     100         123          0.5        AA
 B          AAA     02/05/2005      90         444          1.3        AB
 C          ZZZ     03/07/2006      95         555          2.8        AC
```

**What I already tried:** I am trying to use the merge function to match each dataframe, but I am getting the error  on the "how" part.

```
fnl = db1

fnl = fnl.merge(db2, how='outer', on=['CUSIP'])

fnl = fnl.merge(db3, how='outer', on=['CUSIP'])

fnl = fnl.merge(bte, how='outer', on=['CUSIP'])
```

I also tried the concatenate, but I just get a list of dataframes, instead of a single output.

```
wsframes = [db1 ,db2, db3]

fnl = pd.concat(wsframes, axis=1)
```

**Question:** What is the proper way to do this operation?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: KeyError: 'CUSIP' for the merge procedure. For the concat I get the list of dataframes, but I cannot put them together to do operations.

Comment: Your error suggests that 'CUSIP' is not visible as a column. What do you get when writing `db1['CUSIP']` or `db2['CUSIP']` ?

Comment: Same error in fact. Can that be due to the data being separated from the headers by one empty row?

Comment: what about `db2.columns.tolist()` and `db2.index.tolist()`

Comment: They appear as Unnamed, I guess the problem is the empty row.

Comment: Yes. The problem was the extra row. I removed it and now it works. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
from functools import reduce
#many dataframes
dfs = [df1,df2]
df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.merge(y, on='CUSIP', how='outer'), dfs)
print (df)
  Name CUSIP        Date  Price  Ident Value Class
0    A   XXX  01/01/2001    100    123   0.5    AA
1    B   AAA  02/05/2005     90    444   1.3    AB
2    C   ZZZ  03/07/2006     95    555   2,8    AC
```

But columns in each dataframe has to be different (no matched columns (`CUSIP` here)), else get `_x` and `_y` suffixes:

```
dfs = [df1,df1, df2]
df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.merge(y, on='CUSIP', how='outer'), dfs)
print (df)
  Name_x CUSIP      Date_x  Price_x Name_y      Date_y  Price_y  Ident Value  \
0      A   XXX  01/01/2001      100      A  01/01/2001      100    123   0.5   
1      B   AAA  02/05/2005       90      B  02/05/2005       90    444   1.3   
2      C   ZZZ  03/07/2006       95      C  03/07/2006       95    555   2,8   

  Class  
0    AA  
1    AB  
2    AC
```

Comment: I think he already tried merge, but was complaining of getting an error

Comment: I don't think ti's necessary to use another library like functools. He could also set_index on CUSIP and do the merge.

Comment: @Wli - yes, but if need merge many dataframes, then this is simplier.

Comment: Nice answer ~~!