# Read excel files from a remote server using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of excel files sitting in a directory on a windows server. I am trying to read them using pandas but running into an error. I checked other similar posts but couldn't reach a solution so far. Code below has been referred from [How to read an excel file directly from a Server with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740273/how-to-read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-server-with-python/55011452#55011452)

I am trying to read the files from jupyter notebook installed on a linux server. I am able to ping the windows server from the linux box.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
f = pandas.read_excel(open('//10.xx.xx.xx/directory1/directory2/TestDoc.xlsx','rb'))
```

Error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'//10.xx.xx.xx/directory1/directory2/TestDoc.xlsx'
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:

Also tried without the keyword 'open' but still got the same error.

Comment: pretty sure you don't need the `open` when using pandas, just pass it the path/name of the file

Comment: tried that too...same error

Comment: What are the read permissions for the file?

Comment: Did you use an r at the start? Single \ is an escape char in python

Comment: If you can't access the file like that in your file browser, pandas isn't going to be able to get to it either. Maybe use requests to download it locally and then open?

Comment: like @Datanovice said, `r'//10.xx.xx.xx/directory1/directory2/TestDoc.xlsx'` is worth a try

Comment: I created it with just one row and one column for testing purpose. I am not sure where to check the read permissions

Comment: I also tried using r at the start but got the same error. I am not allowed to move the files from the original location.

Comment: @kkumar you can't download a copy?

Comment: I am able to access the file from my local file browser using backslashes in place of forward.

Comment: I can download a copy and test but my goal is automate the process. In fact I was able to read the contents of the downloaded file using pandas.

Comment: @kkumar you could automate the download, is there a reason that's not as good?

Comment: If your file is on something like s3 you can use the library boto to grab the file save it as a temporary file and then have pandas read it normally. That's what I do

Answer (score 2):

The code samples you are refering to show how to access network drives or UNC paths with Python running on Windows machines. Using a linux host you might need to mount the remote share with valid credentials and then pass a valid path on local file system to [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Please pay close attention to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170008/1126386).

You might explore other ways to [connect to SMB share with `smb://`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203585/how-do-i-connect-to-an-smb-share-requiring-a-user-name-and-password).

Comment: Thank you! Jupyter notebooks I am using are on our hadoop cluster- just wanted to check if I can read the files from the remote server using spark instead of moving them/mounting the remote share. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to mount the remote share/move the files. Just trying to see if there are any other options.